# Can't reload dataTable after jquery response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**HTML**

It is a sidenav to sort the datatable according to list ID's and Sub-list ID's

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">  <!-- sidenav starting-->
<ul>
<li class="categoriesli">All Categories</li>
<?php 
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id, name FROM categories WHERE c_id = 0");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <div id="categorydiv_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="showSubCat(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
    <li id="category_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="categoriesli"><?php echo $row['name']; ?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right pull-right"></span></li>
    </div>
    <li style="padding: 0px;" class="subcategory">
      <ul>
          <?php 
            $result1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT c_id, id, name FROM categories WHERE c_id = '".$row['id']."'");
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
        <div id="subcatdiv_<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="subcategory_<?php echo $rows['c_id']; ?>"  style="display:none;">
        <li id="subcategory_<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" onclick="sortSubCat(<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>, <?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></li>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Before button click**

I can't get data after button click despite got the json data in an array

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  dataTable = $("#datatableId").DataTable({
     "ajax": "retrieve.php",
     "order": []
  });
});
```

**After button click**

```
function sortSubCat(subCatId, catId) {
      $("#datatableId").DataTable().clear();
      $("#datatableId").DataTable().destroy();

    $.ajax({
        url:"retrieve.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{sub_cat_id:subCatId, cat_id:catId},
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            $("#datatableId").DataTable({
                "ajax": response.data
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why you dont use ajax built in datatable?

Comment: check console for error.

Comment: I got invalid JSON response error @urfusion

Comment: Bingo, You got the answer, the response you are getting is not in json format or the json is invalid. if response is not in json then try `json_encode` or if it is in json then check that on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Array [ Array[6] ]  I got ajax response like this @urfusion

Comment: convert it into json by `json_encode`

Comment: I didn't know much about built in datatables. I am new to jquery datatables. please suggest me if any solution @mehdi nejati

Comment: Array [ Array[6] ] I got this data in console @urfusion

Comment: when you are returning data from `retrieve.php` add `return json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a comment about your solution. When the source of data for the DataTable object creation is a json object, it has to be an object with one field "data" that has the table info. In your case, you're removing that format when you pass `response.data`. i think you should pass `"ajax": response`.

But anyway, you can't simplify all that. You don't need to destroy de DataTable object and create it again every time. If you're getting your data from and external source with ajax and you just want to reload the table data, just use datatables `.reload()` function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var subcatId='', catId='';

    var myDataTable = $("#datatableId").DataTable({
        "ajax": { 
            "url": "retrieve.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function(d) {
                d.sub_cat_id = subcatId;
                d.cat_id = catId;
            }
        },
        "order": []
    });

    function sortSubCat(selSubCatId,selCatId) {
        subCatId = selSubCatId;
        catId = selCatId;
        myDataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
});
```

In fact, if you're getting subCatId and catId from two `select` dropdowns, you could even simplify it more (I'm just giving you an example, adapt the `id's` and html elements to your case, you can also introduce parameters value validation, etc.)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myDataTable = $("#datatableId").DataTable({
        "ajax": { 
            "url": "retrieve.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function(d) {
                d.sub_cat_id = $('select#subcatid').val();
                d.cat_id = $('select#catid').val();
            }
        },
        "order": []
    });

    $('button#sortsubcat').click(function() {
        myDataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Every time i am getting the whole data other than the ID's mentioned in function

Comment: Mmm... I see. I've edited the answer. Try that and let me know how it goes

Comment: Yes. you are right. I am getting ID's from two select drop down's but the ID's are dynamic how can i get them in .val()

Comment: Maybe using their DOM position (inside of a div, a table, etc.)? Where are that dropdowns (edit your question and paste the html to be able to see it)?

Comment: Sorry it is a side nav to sort the datatable. I updated my html